# Is it a good practise to use CommonServiceLocator to inject dependencies into base class?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ioc-container, common-service-locator

Currently when I need to inject dependencies into base class, I use the following code:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    readonly IService _service;
    public BaseClass(IService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }
}

public class A : BaseClass
{
    public A(IService service) : base(service)
    {
    }
}

public class B : BaseClass
{
    public B(IService service) : base(service)
    {
    }
}
```

I have to write a lot of duplicate code in all sub classes. To avoid these duplicate code, I think I can use CommonServiceLocator to inject dependencies into the base class:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    readonly IService _service;
    public BaseClass()
    {
        _service = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IService>();
    }
}

public class A : BaseClass
{
}

public class B : BaseClass
{
}
```

This seems to be much simpler, but I'm not sure if this is a good practice.

Thanks

Comment: short answer: no, don't use service locator. there is no duplicate code here.

Comment: @Mauricio Scheffer: No duplicate code? I have to put `(IService service) : base(service)` in the constructor of all sub classes. Sometimes the only reason I create a constructor for a subclass is for injecting dependencies into the base class.

Comment: ... and that's what you should continue to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Requesting a dependency from within a class is called the [Service Locator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern), which is an [anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx). Prevent to minimize the dependency between your application and the IoC framework, even if it is the Common Service Locator.

I would still go for the first approach, but I agree that if the base class always needs that dependency and you have many sub types, this can become cumbersome. In that case, go for property injection:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass()
    {
    }

    public IService Service { get; set; }
}
```

This way your library is free from using a Service Locator. One of the greatest advantages of this approach for me, is that it makes writing unit tests much less painful.

Comment: After read your answer, I decide to use property injection for the BaseViewModel and other base classes that have many subclasses. That saved a lot of code. Thanks for your answer and the links!